# How do I convert Cocoa co-ords from top left == origin to bottom left == origin

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I use CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo to get a list of all windows. It gives me the co-ordinates of each window based upon the origin being the **top-left** of the screen.

If I use NSWindow's setFrame method, the co-ordinates on based upon the origin being the **bottom-left** of the screen.

What's a clean, reliable way to convert from one to the other?

Added: By clean and reliable, I mean, something sure to work regardless whether the user has multiple screens or is using Spaces. I figure there must be a known idiom using library APIs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Math is quite reliable :-)

```
yFromBottom = screenHeight - windowHeight - yFromTop
```

Main screen height is

```
[[[NSScreen screens] objectAtIndex:0] frame].size.height
```

Comment: Note: It seems that window coordinates are always relative to the main screen (not to your window's screen property)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using an NSAffineTransform. If you draw with respect to the default origin and then apply a transform to the view, you can essentially flip things around in one fell  swoop.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this ([from here](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.plugins/browse_thread/thread/fe4d08d63555797b)):

```
NSRect boundsInWindow = [myView convertRect:[myView bounds] toView:nil];
NSRect visibleRectInWindow = [myView convertRect:[myView visibleRect] toView:nil];

// Flip Y to convert NSWindow coordinates to top-left-based window coordinates.
float borderViewHeight = [[myView window] frame].size.height;
boundsInWindow.origin.y = borderViewHeight - NSMaxY(boundsInWindow);
visibleRectInWindow.origin.y = borderViewHeight - NSMaxY(visibleRectInWindow);
```