# convert bottom left orgin position to top left origin position (and the reverse)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quartz-graphics, macos-carbon

I am wondering about the right way to convert a bottom left orgin position to top left origin position (and the oposite operation)  under Mac OS X taking into account:
- Multi screen configurations
- Where these screens can be arranged in all possible configurations.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards,

Comment: Surely it's as simple as negating the y-values for your coordinates.

Comment: not at all. If it was so simple, I'd be happy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [How do I convert Cocoa co-ords from top left == origin to bottom left == origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852875/how-do-i-convert-cocoa-co-ords-from-top-left-origin-to-bottom-left-origin)

Good answers there...